# Receive RFCOMM input from HID device

Tags: android, bluetooth, embedded, hid, rfcomm

I have no experience with embedded systems.

I am programming a smartphone application to receive RFCOMM input from a bluetooth device. This device is an HID remote control with configurable buttons. As I undestand HID is based on RFCOMM.

This is my device: https://serialio.com/products/bluetooth-dongles/imedia-remote-control

Most smartphones have "native" support for HID so that they will handle HID input on OS level - this is my problem. I want to receive the "raw" RFCOMM input in my own application and do different things depending on configuration, input, etc.

How could I approach this?

Comment: Unfortunately HID is not based on RFCOMM, it is based on the lower level L2CAP.

Comment: I agree with comment above, I read multiple technical articles about this topic, and all of them were stating that HID works on L2CAP transport protocol. In fact both HID and RFCOMM come on same level and implemented on top of L2CAP in Bluetooth stack

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you need to connect that devices from from your mobile.

connection is based on RFCOMM communication and this we pass UUID that is

different for chat(mobile to mobile communication) and mobile to other device(Embedded).

if your connection is successful then create one socket between your mobile and your embedded device. After  creation socket perform read and write operation between your mobile and embedded device. read write operation based on communication protocol which is provide by your device vendor.

Comment: This does not answer the principle difficulty of the question - specifically, **how to get around the operating system's desire to handle the device as HID** and access it in a raw mode instead.